# Ruby app on Heroku - Why is my caches_action not refreshing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a RoR app running on Heroku. In my controllers I have simple caches_action statements running, such as this:

```
caches_action :index, :expires_in => 5.minutes

def index 
    @articles = Article.main.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    ....
end
```

In the Article model, items are retrieved based on their published date using scope statements like so:

```
scope :before, lambda{|timenow| {:conditions => ["time <= ?", timenow]}}
scope :published, where(:published => true).order("time DESC")
scope :main, before(Time.now).published
```

Even though I have the caches_action set to 5 minutes, I still have to go in and manually clear the cache for todays article to show at the top of the list, many hours after they're supposed to go live. Is there a global cache setting on Heroku or in Rails I'm missing somewhere?

**More info:**

Today when a new article was not showing up I tried going into the console and typing:

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

This had no effect. I then tried using the same ActiveRecord request as the index controller:

```
Article.main
```

... and it returned the correct articles, including the one that isn't showing up on the site.

Only restarting the server altogether reset the cache and showed the article.

Comment: Have you tried using an explicit expire during the create/update methods instead of worrying about the :expires_in parameter?

Comment: Also, I don't even see expires_in on Rails' documentation page for caches_action. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#action-caching

Comment: Hey I can see an explanation of using expires_in with caches_action here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html

Comment: The problem with using an explicit update or create expire would be that the cache would save at that time when the article is due to go live in a days time, and I would end up with the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a Rails project on heroku that's using action caching. It is appropriately caching the request for 15 seconds and then refreshing the cache.

Is it possible you're not using the dalli gem?

The heroku addon:

```
heroku addons:add memcache:5mb
```

The code:

config/application.rb

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

app/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  caches_action :index, :expires_in => 15.seconds
  def index
    @timestamp = Time.now
  end
end
```

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<h1>hi!</h1>
I was generated at <%= @timestamp %>.
```

Comment: Yep, I'm definitely using Dalli, its in the gemfile and set in production config.

Comment: Well, here's the heroku app where it's working: http://fathomless-inlet-3491.herokuapp.com/. So it's not a heroku problem.

Comment: Are there any Rails settings that might be overriding my models cache_action directive?